# .Net Core Seleniun Tests in Azure DevOps- No Files matched the search pattern error for .Net restore task

Tags: azure, selenium, .net-core, azure-devops, dotnet-restore

Created a .Net core Selenium tests in Azure Repos.
I have the .csproj as well in the Repos.
Added a ASP.Net core task, in the restore task i have given Path to Project as "**/*.csproj".

Got the below error while running the build pipeline.

SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
##[error]No files matched the search pattern

Not sure if the Agent didnt find my .csproj file. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Please check whether my answer can help you. If you have any update in your debugging process, please feel free to comment.

Comment: Thanks for the response!! But in my personal account I was able to run the task but at my client azure org I m getting this error.will check and let you know

Comment: Hello, didn't get your latest news. Is there any updates for this issue? Please feel free to let me know whether my answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue, but the task ran successfully.

My environment:

Agent: `ubuntu-latest`

.Net SDK Version: `3.1.403`

My script:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
```

You can do the following things to locate your issue:

1. Rerun the pipeline using my environment configuration.
2. Write the full and detailed path name. For example, `$(System.defaultWorkingDirectory)/WindowsApp.csproj`.
3. Add a command line task to run dotnet restore directly.
4. Set the `system.debug` variable to `true`. Rerun your pipeline and you will see a more detailed run log.